# Eclipse: Is there a way to force an import in Organize Import to solve an ambiguity?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse on an android project. I updated to Lion and problems began to appear... Trying stuff for hours, no results.

**Here is the problem:**

I have dozens of files *com.stuff.morestuff* in my project.
I would like to crtl+shift+O my project so every import are resolved. 
But, on each file, eclipse ask me to resolve ambiguities.

Therefore, I would like to impose to eclipse to choose the first choice.

**Some clues**

1 - I tried to make rules in the build path, but it's to powerful.
Ex: If i exclude android.R from the build path, then it doesn't appear in the choices but I cannot use it explicitly in my code...

2 - Do it manually —> to long

3 - I tried to configure the Organize Import tool, but didn't succeed.

Thank for your answers!

Comment: What do you mean "resolve ambiguities?" Is it asking you about classes that have the same unqualified name (eg: `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`)? I can't imagine you'd have "dozens of files" that would suffer from this problem unless you decided to manually delete all of the existing imports (or just wrote code without ever bothering to make it compile). And if you did that, well, you learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: :-) dear lord no... I don't know why exactly but eclipse "like to import android.R" (seen on google dev). This is a pain: it hides your R file. I deleted them, and when I wanted to import my R file the problem shows up. It shows up because I use greendroid lib with has its own R file...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use 'Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters'. Create filters for types that you don't want to use. E.g. If you are not interested in types from java.awt package, you can create a filter for the entire package, or you can filter out individual types.

The filtered types are then hidden from the UI, i.e. they are not used in Organize imports or shown in Open Type dialog etc. Note that the types are still visible to the compiler, this is different from fiddling with the build path which will hide the types from the compiler.

Comment: +1: This is my suggestion, too. This way, you can filter out whole packages you never use, or single classes, like java.awt.List, or java.sql.Date. You can still directly import these classes in a file by manually inserting the import statement.

Comment: It was just here... I feel a bit dumb for the moment :-)! Well, thx a lot!

Comment: +1 this heals my chronic pain with java.sql.Date and java.awt.List, other common suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Another 2 years passed and it's the same medication for the same pain :D