# I have integrated may packages in my application, and now R fails to generate

Tags: android

I have developed my application by integrating two applications,

- one entirely developed by myself,
- one form an opensource project that i have modified.

Now time has come to put the two together.

But when I do this R fails to generate properly.

Please see the screen-shoot:
[image]

Thank you for any support!!!!

---

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

It works if I manually do the import

`import com.examples.android.calendar.R;`

DOES IT MAKE SENSE????

Comment: do you any errors in your resource files

Comment: Try to show the actual error inside the package.

Comment: @Raghunandan I agree with you, but as you can see it does generate the R for the package `com.examples.android.calendar`, it does not generate the R for the other packages (in red) therefore I assume the resources files are fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first delete your R.java under gen folder

clean your project

import android.R file

shortcut cmd+shift +o for import R

Comment: when I do that a pop-up comes out `"Problem While Organizing Imports...contains ambiguous reference"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979057/any-reason-to-clean-up-unused-imports-in-java-other-than-reducing-clutter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799657/eclipse-is-there-a-way-to-force-an-import-in-organize-import-to-solve-an-ambigu

please chek them may be you get somthing

Answer (score 1):

If you run a clean on the project it should regenerate all the generated java files, namely `R`.

In `Eclipse`, under the `Project` menu, is an option `build` automatically. That would help you build the `R.java` file everytime modifications are made. The Clean... option is also there under Project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the bin and gen folder and rebuild the project

Comment: how you imported your project? As import->Android->Existing Android Code into Workspace or as General?? if first, do the second^^ had a same problem two days ago and re-import was my solution

Comment: since they were 2 different apps, I have simply copied the sources and the assets of one project into the other... :-/

Comment: i think thats the problem. The second app you added uses their own R, from their MainActivity. Try to remove the bin and gen folders and remove also all imports of R class from your added source code and after rebuild of your project organize imports in that resources

Answer (score 1):

change the build target version and clean the project, after completing that change that build version to previous.

it works for me.